# Weirdest 404 error I've ever seen (commented-out image)

Tags: php, image, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

I've noticed in my server logs that tons of 404 (page not found) errors have been happening for a specific image.

Here are the facts I'm aware of:

- I've searched my entire codebase, and that image filename only occurs in one view, and the image itself is commented out.

  - The HTML of that view is pasted below.
  - (Also, it is not some special case where I'd be dynamically generating the URL of this image file which therefore I wouldn't find in a search of my codebase.)
- When I visit the URL of that view using Chrome, Safari, Edge, etc, I do not see any 404 errors thrown, even in the Inspector console.
- Oddly, even when I visit the URL of the non-existent image itself (`mysite.com/img/people.jpg`), I do not see any 404 errors in the log, even though I see my Laravel 404 error page.
- I continue to see many errors stream into my Nginx error log from various IPs: `failed (2: No such file or directory)` for this image path.

**Is there some browser that my visitors are using that tries to load images even when they are commented out?**

**Or... an even broader question: what else can I try to reproduce this error?** I've never been able to cause a 404 error (for this specific image path) to be added to the log.

HTML of the view:

```
<p>
  Here is some text
</p>
<!--     <img src="/img/people.jpg" alt="people" class="sectionImg img-responsive"/>-->
<img src="/img/beach.jpg" alt="beach" class="sectionImg img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: Maybe the browser has cached an older version of your page with references to the image but the server hasn't synced with it yet so the page still thinks the image exists on the server? Try a hard refresh. Sounds like its been cached somewhere as it only happens on a certain browser.

Comment: Someone else could be trying to display that image on their site with the src tag to your URL.  I'd put a 301 permanent redirect in place and be done.

Comment: What is the referrer, and agent, that generates the 404s? It could be a spider, eg Googlebot, which attempt to parse and visit resources even in JS.

Comment: Seeing the laravel 404 page without seeing a 404 error in the logs is something that should not be happening. If anything you want to reliably log error codes and not log them some of the time.Does nginx also log the requested site? Is it always `yoursite.com` or are there requests to the IP address or some other host?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm not sure how to see anything other than the client's IP. I guess Cloudways (my host provider) has configured the Nginx logs in a particular way. Maybe there is a way for me to get Nginx to start logging agent and referrer (if Cloudways allows such a configuration)?

Comment: @apokryfos I'm now looking at Laravel's Handler.php and see that `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException::class` is included in the `$dontReport` array, so I guess that would explain 404 errors not appearing in the log. But knowing this, it seems weird that I'm *ever* seeing `No such file or directory` errors appear in the Nginx log.

Comment: `$dontReport` should still have the errors logged in the nginx log unless you're rendering the error view and not returning the error number. At any rate, it sounds to me that nginx is serving the default 404 error as though it's not serving the laravel page at all but rather its default homepage, which is what you'd expect from requests to the server IP (op to unknown hosts) instead of the host.

Comment: @apokryfos The same lines in the log that say `No such file or directory` also say `host: "mysite.com"`, so I don't think people are visiting the server IP directly. I have a new hypothesis: most of my traffic comes from Facebook ads, and I wonder if the browser within the Facebook mobile app is somehow reading my commented-out HTML and trying to load that non-existent image. I'll try to reproduce that somehow.

Comment: @Ryan maybe not facebook itself, but badly written web-scrapers might. Comment it out in blade code (use `{{-- --}}`)